# Spark - LinearRegressionWithSGD on Coursera Machine Learning by Stanford University samples

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

**Software Version**: Apache Spark v1.3

**Context**: I've been trying to "translate" Octave/MATLAB code to Scala on Apache Spark. More precisely, I work on *ex1data1.txt* and *ex1data2.txt* from **coursera** practical part *ex1*. I've made such translation into Julia lang (it went smoothly) and now I've been struggling with Spark...without success.

**Problem**: Performance of my implementation on Spark is very poor. I cannot even say it works correctly. That's why for *ex1data1.txt* I added polynomial feature, and I also worked with: theta0 using setIntercept(true) and with extra non-normalized column of 1.0 values(in this case I set Intercept to false). I receive only silly results.
So, then I 've decided to start working with *ex1data2.txt*. Below you can find the code and the expected result. Of course Spark result is wrong.

Did you have similar experience? I will be grateful for your help.

The Scala code for the exd1data2.txt:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.StandardScaler
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.SquaredL2Updater
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.{LinearRegressionModel, LinearRegressionWithSGD, LabeledPoint}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}


object MLibOnEx1data2 extends App {
  val conf = new SparkConf()
  conf.set("spark.app.name", "coursera ex1data2.txt test")

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val input = sc.textFile("hdfs:///ex1data2.txt")

  val trainData = input.map { line =>
    val parts = line.split(',')
    val y = parts(2).toDouble
    val features = Vectors.dense(parts(0).toDouble, parts(1).toDouble)
    println(s"x = $features y = $y")
    LabeledPoint(y, features)
  }.cache()

  // Building the model
  val numIterations = 1500
  val alpha = 0.01

  // Scale the features
  val scaler = new StandardScaler(withMean = true, withStd = true)
    .fit(trainData.map(x => x.features))
  val scaledTrainData = trainData.map{ td =>
    val normFeatures = scaler.transform(td.features)
    println(s"normalized features = $normFeatures")
    LabeledPoint(td.label, normFeatures)
  }.cache()

  val tsize = scaledTrainData.count()
  println(s"Training set size is $tsize")


  val alg = new LinearRegressionWithSGD().setIntercept(true)
  alg.optimizer
    .setNumIterations(numIterations)
    .setStepSize(alpha)
    .setUpdater(new SquaredL2Updater)
    .setRegParam(0.0)  //regularization - off

  val model = alg.run(scaledTrainData)

  println(s"Theta is $model.weights")

  val total1 = model.predict(scaler.transform(Vectors.dense(1650, 3)))

  println(s"Estimate the price of a 1650 sq-ft, 3 br house = $total1 dollars") //it should give ~ $289314.620338

  // Evaluate model on training examples and compute training error
  val valuesAndPreds = scaledTrainData.map { point =>
    val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
    (point.label, prediction)
  }
  val MSE = ((valuesAndPreds.map{case(v, p) => math.pow((v - p), 2)}.mean()) / 2)
  println("Training Mean Squared Error = " + MSE)



  // Save and load model
  val trySaveAndLoad = util.Try(model.save(sc, "myModelPath"))
    .flatMap { _ => util.Try(LinearRegressionModel.load(sc, "myModelPath")) }
    .getOrElse(-1)

  println(s"trySaveAndLoad result is $trySaveAndLoad")
}
```

STDOUT result is:

> Training set size is 47
>
> Theta is (weights=[52090.291641275864,19342.034885388926],
>   intercept=181295.93717032953).weights
>
> Estimate the price of a 1650 sq-ft, 3 br house = 153983.5541846754
>   dollars
>
> Training Mean Squared Error = 1.5876093757127676E10
>
> trySaveAndLoad result is -1

Comment: It would be useful if you omit input parsing and provide example input. If you already have working model you can simply generate some points according to the parameters.

Comment: @zero323, I've asked coursera whether I have rights to put here any samples from coursera site.
Maciek

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some digging I believe there is nothing here. First I saved content of the `valuesAndPreds` to text file:

```
valuesAndPreds.map{
   case {x, y} => s"$x,$y"}.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("results.txt")'
```

Rest of the code is written in R.

First lets create a model using closed form solution:

```
# Load data
df <- read.csv('results.txt/ex1data2.txt', header=FALSE)
# Scale features
df[, 1:2] <- apply(df[, 1:2], 2, scale)
# Build linear model 
model <- lm(V3 ~ ., df)
```

For reference:

```
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = V3 ~ ., data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-130582  -43636  -10829   43698  198147 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   340413       9637  35.323  < 2e-16 ***
V1            110631      11758   9.409 4.22e-12 ***
V2             -6650      11758  -0.566    0.575    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 66070 on 44 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7329,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7208 
F-statistic: 60.38 on 2 and 44 DF,  p-value: 2.428e-13
```

Now prediction:

```
closedFormPrediction <- predict(model, df)
closedFormRMSE <- sqrt(mean((closedFormPrediction - df$V3)**2))
plot(
   closedFormPrediction, df$V3,
   ylab="Actual", xlab="Predicted",
   main=paste("Closed form, RMSE: ", round(closedFormRMSE, 3)))
```

[image]'

Now we can compare above to SGD results:

```
sgd <- read.csv('results.txt/part-00000', header=FALSE)
sgdRMSE <- sqrt(mean(sgd$V2 - sgd$V1)**2)

plot(
   sgd$V2, sgd$V1, ylab="Actual",
   xlab="Predicted", main=paste("SGD, RMSE: ", round(sgdRMSE, 3)))
```

[image]

Finally lets compare both:

```
plot(
   sgd$V2, closedFormPrediction,
   xlab="SGD", ylab="Closed form", main="SGD vs Closed form")
```

[image]

So, result are clearly not perfect but nothing seems to be completely off here.

Comment: I've made the same excercise as you for Julia. That is what I've got: [link](http://1drv.ms/1GN1NKy). The predictions on Spark are different. OK, but how can we interpret it more precisely?

Comment: In addition, cost function (MSE) for 1500 iterations, alpha=0.01 is as follows:
Spark ->  s=1.5876093757127676E10;
Julia -> j=2.0432835766373606e9;
s > j -> true;
s/j = 7.769 (~8 times larger).

Comment: Continuing: iterations=18000, alhpa=0.003; Spark MSE -> s2 = 1.4826734808130558E10; s2/j = 7.256 (7.25 times larger than Julia). Don't you think Spark cannot find global optima, but instead of this it falls into local optima?

Comment: Since least squares problem means convex function a local minimum is not a problem. MSE  you report for Julia is simply not realistic. It would mean you can do better than exact analytical solution. Given a step pattern we see when compared Closed form and SGD solution I am pretty sure that problem is related to the second feature. I it is relatively strongly correlated to the first one (0.5599672) and it is not significant in a model obtained from closed form solution.

Comment: Another problem mentioned by [Till Rohrmann](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4815083/till-rohrmann) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31610206/1560062) is that gradient descent  is sensitive when it comes to step size. Have you tried to use grid search to optimize parameters? From what I remember from Machine Learning class step was adjusted with iterations, am I correct?

Comment: Let me remind that ex1data.txt works also poorly (there is only one feature). If you say that cost function is convex for multiple features you probably are right. I'm not so sure right now:). The same cost as for Julia is for Octave code in ML practical part (bug in teaching materials?). For Spark I've tried even alpha=0.001, 0.002.

Comment: I've finished ML course in early 2013 so there could be some change in a materials. Could you provide coefficients from Julia/Octave?

Comment: iterations: 1500; alpha=0.01; octave_theta=[340412.563014;110540.566546;-6558.990548 ]; julia_theta=[340412.563014392,110540.56654627321,-6558.99054811402]