# Spark mllib predicting weird number or NaN

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, gradient-descent

I am new to Apache Spark and trying to use the machine learning library to predict some data.  My dataset right now is only about 350 points.  Here are 7 of those points:

```
"365","4",41401.387,5330569
"364","3",51517.886,5946290
"363","2",55059.838,6097388
"362","1",43780.977,5304694
"361","7",46447.196,5471836
"360","6",50656.121,5849862
"359","5",44494.476,5460289
```

Here's my code:

```
def parsePoint(line):
    split = map(sanitize, line.split(','))
    rev = split.pop(-2)
    return LabeledPoint(rev, split)

def sanitize(value):
    return float(value.strip('"'))

parsedData = textFile.map(parsePoint)
model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, iterations=10)

print model.predict(parsedData.first().features)
```

The prediction is something totally crazy, like `-6.92840330273e+136`.  If I don't set iterations in `train()`, then I get `nan` as a result.  What am I doing wrong?  Is it my data set (the size of it, maybe?) or my configuration?

Comment: [Multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) is a common cause of numerical instability in linear regression.  A regularization term can help, as can doing dimensionality reduction first.  I can't see an obvious case by visually inspecting the sample data, but sometimes it isn't obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `LinearRegressionWithSGD` uses stochastic gradient descent (SGD) to optimize the weight vector of your linear model. SGD is really sensitive to the provided `stepSize` which is used to update the intermediate solution.

What SGD does is to calculate the gradient `g` of the cost function given a sample of the input points and the current weights `w`. In order to update the weights `w` you go for a certain distance in the opposite direction of `g`. The distance is your step size `s`.

```
w(i+1) = w(i) - s * g
```

Since you're not providing an explicit step size value, MLlib assumes `stepSize = 1`. This seems to not work for your use case. I'd recommend you to try different step sizes, usually lower values, to see how `LinearRegressionWithSGD` behaves:

```scala
LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, numIterartions = 10, stepSize = 0.001)
```

Comment: When I set `step=0.0000000000000001` and `iterations=500`, it works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that with default parameters (`miniBatchFraction` equal to 1.0) it is no longer stochastic.